# Determine file/folder path based on root + web link?

Tags: string, delphi, path, delphi-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Conversion between absolute and relative paths in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329472/conversion-between-absolute-and-relative-paths-in-delphi)

I'm trying to figure out how to get a file path based on an original web link. In my application, I have two values:

fRootDir: String = `C:\Some Directory\My Web Site\` (Application directory)

fImgPath: String = `../Some Other Web Site/SomeImage.jpg` (From a web page)

Result needs to be: `C:\Some Directory\Some Other Web Site\SomeImage.jpg`

Notice the `../` in front of the image path. This could be many in a row like `../../../` which each `../` means *go up a folder*. The image `SomeImage.jpg` is in fact a location at `C:\Some Directory\Some Other Web Site\`.

Also note that web links use `/` - which is not a problem to convert to `\`. The problem is with noticing `..` and actually looking in the above directory for each.

Now I need to combine the two properties to result in a final path of where to find `SomeImage.jpg` on the computer, based on the root and the image paths.

Comment: @Serg Actually thanks for pointing that out, I found better answers there, but the ones here are still good because they're short and simple :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even simpler:

```
const
  RootFolder = 'D:\PerforceThuis\Marjan\Probeersels\StackOverflow';
  RelativeFolder = '..\..\General\Plugins';
begin
  WriteLn(ExpandFileName(IncludeTrailingBackSlash(RootFolder)+RelativeFolder));
```

Tested in D6. Outputs:

```
D:\PerforceThuis\Marjan\General\Plugins
```

Comment: It looks like this will work, but I have to get in front of my Delphi to try it out - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is very easy using the [`PathCanonicalize` SHLWAPI function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773569%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Just do

```
function SimplifyPath(const Path: string): string;
var
  buf: array[0..MAX_PATH - 1] of char;
begin
  if PathCanonicalize(buf, PChar(Path)) then
    result := buf
  else
    RaiseLastOSError;
end;
```

Comment: I don't understand - there's only one parameter? I have two different strings to pass into this function: Root Path (C:\SomeFolder\) and Relative Path (../SomeOtherFolder/SomeFile.abc) - the two need to be combined. I don't see how this function can accomplish this.

Comment: `SimplifyPath(RootPath + RelativePath)`