# What is opposite of ExtractRelativePath in Pascal?

Tags: freepascal, lazarus

I often use ExtractRelativePath to get the relative path between two path. But i cannot see any function opposite to it. This is an example from freepascal.org:

```
Uses sysutils;

Procedure Testit (FromDir,ToDir : String);

begin
  Write ('From "',FromDir,'" to "',ToDir,'" via "');
  Writeln (ExtractRelativePath(FromDir,ToDir),'"');
end;

Begin
 Testit ('/pp/src/compiler','/pp/bin/win32/ppc386');
 Testit ('/pp/bin/win32/ppc386','/pp/src/compiler');
 Testit ('e:/pp/bin/win32/ppc386','d:/pp/src/compiler');
 Testit ('e:\pp\bin\win32\ppc386','d:\pp\src\compiler');
End.
```

Output of this program

```
From "/pp/src/compiler" to "/pp/bin/win32/ppc386" via "../bin/win32/ppc386"
From "/pp/bin/win32/ppc386" to "/pp/src/compiler" via "../../src/compiler"
From "e:/pp/bin/win32/ppc386" to "d:/pp/src/compiler" via "../../src/compiler"
From "e:\pp\bin\win32\ppc386" to "d:\pp\src\compiler" via "../../src/compiler"
```

I need a function F to perform reverse action of ExtractRelativePath, for example:

```
F('/pp/src/compiler', '../bin/win32/ppc386') return '/pp/bin/win32/ppc386'.
```

---

Do you know any function like this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conversion between absolute and relative paths in Delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329472/conversion-between-absolute-and-relative-paths-in-delphi)

Comment: @GolezTrol that is not about expanding, that si about merging full with relative.

Comment: http://www.delphipages.com/forum/showthread.php?t=173795

Comment: http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/concatpaths.html

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : I'm sorry, this is only my mistake, I've edit the content from ../bin/win32/ppc386 to /pp/bin/win32/ppc386.

Comment: OK. I've added another correction.

Comment: Thank you for your time. But your correction is not right. The first parameter is '/pp/src/compiler' but not '/pp/src/compiler/', so the second parameter must be '../bin/win32/ppc386' not '../../bin/win32/ppc386'. I'm reading the answers.

Comment: @GolezTrol : I think that the answers in [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329472/conversion-between-absolute-and-relative-paths-in-delphi) is too complex, I've read that link before ask this question. And I need a simplier solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, sure. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.IOUtils.TPath.Combine

**System.IOUtils.TPath.Combine**

```
  class function Combine(const Path1, Path2: string): string; inline; static;
```

> Description
>
> Combines two paths strings.
>
> Call Combine to obtain a new combined path from two distinct paths. If
>   the second path is absolute, Combine returns it directly; otherwise
>   Combine returns the first path concatenated with the second one.

---

Above was written when the question was tagged by [delphi](/questions/tagged/delphi)

Now, for FPC simple scan through **SysUtils** sources lands you onto

- c:\codetyphon\fpcsrc\rtl\objpas\sysutils\finah.inc

Which has

```
function ConcatPaths(const Paths: array of String): String;
```

Which is documented at

- http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/concatpaths.html

> ConcatPaths
>
> Concatenate an array of paths to form a single path
>
> Declaration
>
> Source position: finah.inc line 42
>          function ConcatPaths( const Paths: array of ):;
>
> Description
>
> ConcatPaths will concatenate the different path components in Paths to
>   a single path. It will insert directory separators between the various
>   components of the path as needed. No directory separators will be
>   added to the beginning or the end of the path, and none will be taken
>   away.

Example

```
program ex96;

{ This program demonstrates the Concatpaths function }

uses sysutils;

begin
  // will write /this/path/more/levels/
  Writeln(ConcatPaths(['/this/','path','more/levels/']));
  // will write this/path/more/levels/
  Writeln(ConcatPaths(['this/','path','more/levels/']));
  // will write this/path/more/levels
  Writeln(ConcatPaths(['this/','path','more/levels']));
end.
```

Comment: The question is about FreePascal and Lazarus

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Oh, indeed. Thanks for fixing tags. But let this answer remain for a while as a waarning to further readers

Comment: I'm using Lazarus and I didn't find System.IOUtils.pas. With `ConcatPaths`, if both A and B is absolute path, ConcatPaths return `A+[+'/']+B` but B is expected. Are there some functions better?

Comment: ConcatPaths is OK, but need some more instructions.

Comment: yes, it probably at least needs IsPathAbsoluteOrRelative - which exists in IOUtils, but dunno if in lazarus