# Delphi combine absolute and relative pathname

Tags: delphi

(Using Delphi 2010)

Is there a simple but stable way to combine absolute and relative filenames, so that the resulting filename is a well-formed filename?

```
dir1\dir2\dir3\ + ..\filename => dir1\dir2\filename
dir1\dir2\dir3\ + ..\..\filename => dir1\filename
dir1\dir2\dir3\ + .\filename => dir1\dir2\dir3\filename
```

Path.Combine comes to mind, but it resolves to something like

```
dir1\dir2\dir3\ + .\filename => dir1\dir2\dir3\.\filename
```

which does not seem to be a well-formed filename

Thanks a lot!
Willem

Comment: After you called combine - try to amend the result with either `SysUtils.ExpandFileName` or with `Windows.GetFullPathName`

Comment: PS. it is well-formed, it is not canonical, but it is well-formed nonetheless

Answer (score 0):

I post this as an answer because I can't flag it as duplicate for some reason.

Check the RelToAbs function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329472/conversion-between-absolute-and-relative-paths-in-delphi)