# how to make 2 step back? ..\..\ ExtractFilePath (paramstr(0))

Tags: delphi

***Hi Guys ,I need help!***

When I extract file path with **ExtractFilePath (paramstr(0))**

I'm getting this: `C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\example13.02\Win32\Debug`
    but I need to go 2 step back. `C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\example13.02\`

I don't know, How?

**ExtractFilePath (paramstr(0))** how to make 2 step back ....\

**I tried** (ExtractFilePath (paramstr(0))+'....\')

result:

```
C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\example13.02\Win32\D‌​ebug\..\..\
```

Comment: C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\example13.02\Win32\D‌​ebug\..\..\ is the same as C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\example13.02\

Comment: FWIW you might use PathCanonicalize - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5329520/587106

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ExtractFileDir(ExtractFileDir(ExtractFileDir(ParamStr(0))))
```